# Rotate 3d javascript sprite

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an image sprite including 8 frames of my character (game hero) that is turned to right. I want that hero to be turned to left on key hold left. Now it is turned to right all the time. I am drawing the image on 2d canvas context like so:

```
ctx.translate(x, y);
// TODO - here I need to rotate it in 3d
// ctx.rotate();
ctx.translate(-x,-y);

ctx.drawImage(i, cycle * spriteW, 0, spriteW, spriteH, x, y, spriteW, spriteH);
ctx.restore();
```

Is it possible to rotate it using 2d context or do I need to change some logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this `ctx.scale(-1, 1);`. But it's better to load a flipped version of your sprite when the game loads, and to switch between your left and your right sprite. This is faster than to flip the sprite.

Comment: Thank you. Scale did not really work out for me. Maybe I used it wrong. But I used the second way you suggested - I loaded flipped spread and it works nicely. Thanks again.

Comment: You forgot to translate, and instead of storing+fetching a new image, if you are concerned by performances, generate the flipped version at the init of your app on an offscreen canvas.